# Reduce image width and height using imagemagick without blur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to reduce image width and height from 600*400 to 120*120 using following comment in imagemagick

convert 'old.png' -resize 120x120 -quality 100 'new.png'

After reducing size image looks too blur.
Is there any way to do this using imagemagick?

Comment: Do you use `dragonfly`? Or something else? Show code fragment where you exactly processing images.

Comment: How much reduction (in percent) are you doing? If very large, that could be the issue. Also -quality values mean something totally different for PNG than for JPG. I am not sure what -quality 100 means for PNG. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. Try without -quality 100. Is it any better? As mentioned below you can add -unsharp to sharpen the result. Or you could choose a different -filter option such as carton. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/ and https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/nicolas/. What version of Imagemagick are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could try sharpening your image with -unsharp 1.5x1+0.7+0.02